# How Can I Look In An Array Of Arrays Of Objects And Check To See Whether It Is As Expected With The Correct Values When Writing Tests?

Tags: javascript, arrays, testing, aws-cdk

I would like to ascertain there are specific objects with specific key/value pairs in the returned array. I need to do this for testing, where the outcome is either `>0` or `true`/`false`.

```
const array = [
    [
      {
        Action: ["sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility", "sqs:DeleteMessage", "sqs:GetQueueAttributes", "sqs:GetQueueUrl", "sqs:ReceiveMessage"],
        Effect: "Allow",
        Resource: { "Fn::ImportValue": "stackName" },
      },
    ],
    [ { Action: ["logs:DeleteRetentionPolicy", "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"], Effect: "Allow", Resource: "*" } ],
    [
      { Action: ["states:SendTaskFailure", "states:SendTaskSuccess"], Effect: "Allow", Resource: "*" },
      {
        Action: ["sqs:ChangeMessageVisibility", "sqs:DeleteMessage", "sqs:GetQueueAttributes", "sqs:GetQueueUrl", "sqs:ReceiveMessage"],
        Effect: "Allow",
        Resource: { "Fn::ImportValue": "secondStackName" },
      },
    ],
  ];
```

**How can I write functions that do the following?**

1. When the `Resource` `Fn::ImportValue` is `stackName`, ensure the array is as exactly described in the code.
2. Ensure there is an `Action` array of ["logs:DeleteRetentionPolicy", "logs:PutRetentionPolicy"] with a `Resource` of `"*"`.
3. When the `Resource` `Fn::ImportValue` is `secondStackName`, ensure the array is as exactly described in the code.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Adding some code to the question will indicate which testing framework you are using.

Comment: My question would be, does it matter? Take the array, see if an object exists, and if it does, return true. That's the goal. Nonetheless, I'm open to being wrong, so please let me know.